# Generate big numbers with Math random in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to generate 26 digit numbers with Math.random, but when I use this:
`Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000000000000000000000) + 900000000000000000000000000`
I gets `9.544695043285823e+26`

Comment: Remember, such large numbers, if represented as numbers rather than strings, will not be accurate to the integer (check out `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`)

Comment: Exactly what seems to be the problem? `9.544695043285823e+26` is a darn big number with actually 27 digits, as `e+26` means that you should move the decimal separator 26 places to the right.

Comment: you can use a library like [BigInteger.js](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js/) to generate random big integers (as strings) in any base and with any number of digits (up to cpu memory limit of course)

Answer (score 6):

Modern browsers support [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) and `bigint` primitive type and we can combine it with a random generated array containing 8 bytes (*the sizeof `bigint` is 8 bytes (64 bits)*).

### 1. Generating Random [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) Performance Wise

We can generate a random hex string of 16 characters length and apply it directly to [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt):

```js
const hexString = Array(16)
  .fill()
  .map(() => Math.round(Math.random() * 0xF).toString(16))
  .join('');

const randomBigInt = BigInt(`0x${hexString}`);

// randomBigInt will contain a random Bigint
```

```js
document.querySelector('#generate').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const output = [];
  let lines = 10;

  do {
    const hexString = Array(16)
      .fill()
      .map(() => Math.round(Math.random() * 0xF).toString(16))
      .join('');
    const number = BigInt(`0x${hexString}`);
 
    output.push(`${
        number.toString().padStart(24)
      } : 0x${
        hexString.padStart(16, '0')
      }`);
  } while (--lines > 0);

  document.querySelector('#numbers').textContent = output.join('\n');
});
```

```html
<button id="generate">Generate</button>
<pre id="numbers"><pre>
```

### 2. Generating Random [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) from random bytes array

If we want to use `Uint8Array` or if we want more control over the bits manipulation, we can combine [`Array.prototype.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) with [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to generate an array containing 8 random byte number values (**beware this is around 50% slower than the above method**):

```js
const randomBytes = Array(8)
  .fill()
  .map(() => Math.round(Math.random() * 0xFF));

// randomBytes will  contain something similar to this:
// [129, 59, 98, 222, 20, 7, 196, 244]
```

Then we use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to initialize a [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) of zero value and left shift each randum byte value its *position X 8 bits* and applying *bitwise or* to the current value of each `reduce` iteration:

```js
const randomBigInt = randomBytes
  .reduce((n, c, i) => n | BigInt(c) << BigInt(i) * 8n, 0n);

// randomBigInt will contain a random Bigint
```

#### Working example generating 10 random `BigInt` values

```js
document.querySelector('#generate').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const output = [];
  let lines = 10;

  do {
    const number = Array(8)
      .fill()
      .map(() => Math.round(Math.random() * 0xFF))
      .reduce((n, c, i) => n | BigInt(c) << BigInt(i) * 8n, 0n);
 
    output.push(`${
        number.toString().padStart(24)
      } : 0x${
        number.toString(16).padStart(16, '0')
      }`);
  } while (--lines > 0);

  document.querySelector('#numbers').textContent = output.join('\n');
});
```

```html
<button id="generate">Generate</button>
<pre id="numbers"><pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers in JavaScript (and a lot of other languages) can contain only [about 15.955 digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) without losing precision. For bigger numbers you can look into JS libraries, or concatenate few numbers as strings. For example:

```js
console.log( Math.random().toString().slice(2, 15) + Math.random().toString().slice(2, 15) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) where what you really want to do is generate a sequence of 26 random digits. You don't necessarily have to use `Math.random`. Whenever one mentions randomness it's important to specify how that randomness is distributed, otherwise you could end up with [a paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)).

I'll assume you want each of the 26 digits to be independently randomly chosen uniformly from each of the 10 digits from 0 to 9, but I can also see a common interpretation being that the first digit must not be 0, and so that digit would be chosen uniformly from numbers 1 to 9.

Other answers may tempt you to choose a random bigint value using what amounts to random bits, but their digits will not be randomly distributed in the same way, since their maximum value is not a power of 10. For a simple example consider that a random 4 bit binary value in decimal will range from 00 to 15, and so the second digit will have a 12/16(=75%) chance of being 0 to 5, though it should be 60%.

As for an implementation, there's many ways to go about it. The simplest way would be to append to a string 26 times, but there are more potentially efficient ways that you could investigate for yourself if you find the performance isn't adequate. [`Math.random` has a roughly uniform distribution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) from 0 to 1, but by being double precision it only has 15 or so significant decimal digits to offer us, so for each call to `Math.random` we should be able to retrieve up to 15 out of 26 decimal digits. Using this fact, I would suggest the following compromise on ease of readability and efficiency:

```js
function generate26Digits() {
  const first13 = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.pow(10, 13)).toFixed(0).padStart(13, "0");
  const next13 = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.pow(10, 13)).toFixed(0).padStart(13, "0");
  return first13 + next13;
}

console.log(generate26Digits())
```

This solution is not cryptographically secure however, and so I will direct readers to use [`Crypto.getRandomValues`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues) if you need more security for this for some reason.

If you then want to do math on this number as well without losing precision, you will have to use `bigint` types as others have suggested.

Answer (score -1):

If I use a 6 decillion LG about 72.9 million out of 300 but when I switch to 10 centillion it comes like this 10 ^ 999 - 99999 + 26 just like how 9 - 9 - 9 - 9 - googolplex is equal to 0 googolplex

Comment: very very funny!