# Generate a random number with fixed digit without leading zero

Tags: javascript

I'm using this one liner to generate a random 18 digit number :

```
Math.floor(100000000000000000 + Math.random() * 900000000000000000)
```

The problem is that it always contains one or more zeros at the end, and I don't understand why.

How can I generate a really random number that always contains 18 digits, and without a leading zero?

Comment: Relevant: [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/307179)

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66993210/4543207) up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many digits, you're running against the limit to precision in a javascript number.

Comment: Oh ok thanks, I see. So is there a good solution to still generate a "unique enough" 18 digit number? without a leading zero

Comment: @Dwix Generate two numbers and concatenate them as a string.

Comment: Not storing it as a javascript 'number'.  If you want to use it as such you need to find a [javascript library](https://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/) (or write your own) that lets you use more precision.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a Problem with the max number Range. You can hack it like this. And it is a better Random number.

```
Math.floor(10000000000000000 + Math.random() * 90000000000000000)+ "" + Math.floor(Math.random()* 100)
```

But if you parse to int you have the same problem.

Comment: I guess this is the way to go, but testing the first part alone `Math.floor(10000000000000000 + Math.random() * 90000000000000000)` it still mostly outputs a number ending with 0, why is that?

Comment: Another thing, this solution sometimes outputs a 19 digit number instead of 18 though, where's the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this so far is to generate two numbers (10 digits + 8 digits) & concatenate them as follow:

```
Math.floor(1000000000 + Math.random() * 9000000000) + "" + Math.floor(10000000 + Math.random() * 90000000)
```